# View: Distinct list of all referenced entities

Tags: 8, views

Basic setup: 3 content types

- **Festival**
- **Event**
- **Speaker**

**Event** has a entity 1-to-1 reference field containing a **Festival**.

**Event** also has a 1-to-many reference field containing **Speakers**.

How can I set up a View to list all of the Speakers taking part in a Festival? (A Speaker can take part in more than one Event).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view of **events** with relationship to the **speakers** and contextual filter to **festival**

[image]

For filtering duplicates you have to turn on aggregation as seen above and setup body `aggregation settings: group column: format`

[image]

The contexual settings for festival are

[image]

NOTE: To see preview for a festival put a festival node id in the `contextual filter` and press preview

Finally you can put the view block display on content region or any other region from  `structure > block layout` and the block with relevant event/speakers will be present when you visit a festival page

Comment: Great! I was missing the aggregation. And also trying to show a _rendered entity_ and not _fields_. Now I have the rendered entity as a field.